# Website garbled up in IE8, when in High Security Mode in internet zone

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

As subject says, my page looks all garbled up when viewed in ie8 when high security is enabled in internet zone

Here are screen-shots in both conditions

(Medium Security: http://i41.tinypic.com/fbdv9e.jpg) and (High Security: http://i40.tinypic.com/v8mqv6.jpg)

I know there are some html validation errors, which i've fixed to the best of my knowledge still have spent just a lot of time fixing these ie errors.. The site looks fine in firefox, opera, chrome and safari only this damn ie

All help appreciated.. if anyone wants to look at the css, will be happy to share.. 
Thanks,

Comment: maybe some scripts / plugins are located on another domain ?

Comment: doubtful.. ive gone through all the code over and over again.. the html or css doesnt have anything linking to another domain..

Comment: weird, but try loading site in IE9, and look for security messages in F12 console.

Comment: haha, super weird.. the site works fine in ie9 and ie10 even when security is turned up to high.. they definitely fixed some html parsing issues there... i'll have a look at f12 console to see if it throws any errors. many thanks,.

Answer (score 0):

Are the resources definitely on the exact same domain? It might be worth checking whether you have (eg) your page being served from http://example.com and your resources from http://www.example.com. Or some other similar variation of different subdomains.

Not sure if that would cause this, but it might be a possibility!